# Why this is printing none after every output of print command

Tags: python-2.7

```
def earlier_semester(w1,w2):
 if w1[1]<w2[1] or w1[0]=="Fall":
  print "True"
 else:
  print "False" 
A = ('spring',2015)
B = ('spring',2014)
C = ('Fall',2015)
D = ('Fall',2014) 

print earlier_semester(A,B) 
print earlier_semester(D,A)
print earlier_semester(A,C)
```

Getting answer and then None on the next line like:
False
None
True 
None

Answer (score 1):

The command `print earlier_semester(A,B)` calls the function `earlier_semester` with the arguments `A,B` and prints what that function returns.  It returns, by default, `None`.  Therefore `None` prints.

Let's demonstrate this.  First, let's define a very simple function:

```
>>> def somefn():
...     print "Hi"
...
```

Let's run the function:

```
>>> somefn2()
'Hi'
```

Now, let's print the function:

```
>>> print somefn()
Hi
None
```

The problem is that `somefn` has no explicit return statement.  That means, by default, it returns `None`.

Let's try this again with a return statment:

```
>>> def somefn2():
...    return "Hi"
... 
>>> somefn2()
'Hi'
>>> print somefn2()
Hi
```

It no longer prints `None`.

Comment: Thanks a ton John that really helped me. I am new learner to python so asked such dumb question :(

Answer (score 0):

You should use return inside the function instead of `print`. something like the below:

```
def earlier_semester(w1,w2):
   if w1[1]<w2[1] or w1[0]=="Fall":
      return "True"
   else:
      return "False"
```

If you no `return` at the end of function, you got `None` default value!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to type print("True") or print("False") for python to print out True/False.

Just type:

1. return True
2. return False

Python will automatically print out 'True' and 'False' values. 
If you use your method, **you're not defining what the function returns when the condition evaluates**. The reason for this is because Python Functions work in a way so that it has to return "something".

So it does what you tell it to it:

1. Print "True" or Print "False"
2. Then prints out "None" after each function call.

Refer to amended code below:

```
def earlier_semester(w1,w2):
 if w1[1]<w2[1] or w1[0]=="Fall":
    return True
 else:
    return False
A = ('spring',2015)
B = ('spring',2014)
C = ('Fall',2015)
D = ('Fall',2014) 

print(earlier_semester(A,B))
print(earlier_semester(D,A))
print(earlier_semester(A,C))
```